# Shaking effect in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I was just trying to use a function of jQuery in my JavaScript code for styling. I want that whenever the required text field is empty, the textfield should shake, but I can't do it. Please help me out I just wasted my whole night on it. Finally asking for your help. I hope that you people get my question.

The code is given below

```
function validate() {
  var em = document.getElementById("email_value").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("password_value").value;

  if(em == "") {
    shakeIt();
  }                   
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  function shakeIt() {
    $("input").effect("shake", { times:5}, 50);
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that `$("input").effect("shake", { times:5}, 50);` will shake _all_ input elements, not just the one(s) that failed validation.

Comment: Yea! i know, i was just trying to make it work at least. btw thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validate()
{
    var em = document.getElementById("email_value").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password_value").value;

    if(em == "")
    {
        shakeIt();
    }
}

function shakeIt()
{
    $("input").effect("shake",
    {
        times: 5
    }, 50);
}
```

Don't wrap it in $(document).ready() function, because your shakeIt function is not longer in global scope, if you do so.