# how to change text field color using JavaScript and shake that field?

Tags: javascript

**strong text**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(form) {
    if (form.userName.value == "") {
        alert("Please Enter your User Name Or e-mail..");
        form.userName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    //password empty or not
    if (form.password.value == "") {
        alert("Password field cannot be empty");
        form.password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (form.password.value != form.rePassword.value) {
        alert("Your password not matched");
        form.rePassword.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style` attribute:  `.style.property=your style`

```
 form.userName.style.color="red";
```

For Shake effect: [Shake textbox when validation fails using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439567/shake-textbox-when-validation-fails-using-jquery)

[Shaking effect in my javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413691/shaking-effect-in-my-javascript-code)

Comment: @user876345 he means the 'shake' thing in the question.

Comment: i am new in stackoverflow. i know some problem solutions how can post it at stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If using Jquery use `$("#userName").CSS('backgroundColor','red');` .

If Plain Javascript

```
document.getElementById("text1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("text1").style("backgroundColor":"red");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do background color to red then follow this

http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
$("#userName").CSS('backgroundColor','red');
```

And now shaking efffect will be done like this but don't forget to include jquery library into your application

```
$( "#userName" ).effect( "bounce" );
```

I hope this will help you